# When I start Microsoft Edge in headless mode with rust-headless-chrome, an unknown window appears

Tags: rust, puppeteer, microsoft-edge, google-chrome-headless

I want to automate Microsoft Edge with [rust-headless-chrome](https://crates.io/crates/headless_chrome) without opening any windows.

I started Edge in headless mode with the following Rust code:

```rs
use headless_chrome::browser::{Browser, LaunchOptions};
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

fn main() {
    let _browser = Browser::new(LaunchOptions {
        headless: true,
        path: Some(PathBuf::from(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe")),
        args: vec![OsStr::new("--profile-directory=Default")],
        ..Default::default()
    }).unwrap();
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
}
```

Then the following unknown window appeared:
[image]

I tried adding the following arguments, which seemed promising to improve the problem, but the results did not change.

- `--headless`
- `--silent-launch`
- `--disable-logging`

```rs
fn main() {
    let _browser = Browser::new(LaunchOptions {
        headless: true,
        path: Some(PathBuf::from(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe")),
        args: vec![
            OsStr::new("--profile-directory=Default"),
            OsStr::new("--headless"),
            OsStr::new("--silent-launch"),
            OsStr::new("--disable-logging")],
        ..Default::default()
    }).unwrap();
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
}
```

My environment is as follows:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 22H2 64-bit
- Rust toolchain: nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
- rustc: 1.75.0-nightly (1c05d50c8 2023-10-21)
- headless_chrome (`rust-headless-chrome`): 1.0.5
- Microsoft Edge: 118.0.2088.61 (Official build) (64-bit)

Is it possible to run Edge with `rust-headless-chrome` automatically without opening any windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating the crate from 1.0.5 to 1.0.6 released on October 23, 2023.

Thank you for your help and suggestions.
I will mark this question as resolved.

It seems that there was [a change](https://github.com/rust-headless-chrome/rust-headless-chrome/pull/398) in the update to 1.0.6 that prevents the pop-up screen from appearing when launching the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new headless mode which has been released recently. Just try: `--headless=new`. For more information, you can refer to https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the method you mentioned, but unfortunately it did not work in my environment.